# Hide Woocommerce Tax rate label name in front end

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, label, tax

What a dreadful Problem. If i delete the Tax Rate Name under

```
.../wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=tax&section=standard
```

and save the changes, it displays (in my case) "Mehrwertsteuer" (means Tax Rate) instead of nothing.

Any idea how to solve this issue - for example to hide the text in the frontend with css is not possible. I tried a

```
&nbsp;
```

but in this case i get a space behind my text in the frontend and this looks bad. I was also not able to find a filter function. Thx in advance

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom hooked function hooked in **`woocommerce_rate_label`** filter hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rate_label', 'custom_tax_rate_label', 10, 2 );
function custom_tax_rate_label( $rate_name, $key ){
    return '';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

This will remove tax label name everywhere in front end. If you wish, you can use [conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) to hide where you need to do it.

Comment: Perfect! In the meantime i used an empty `<span></span>` tag. Works to and no need for the filter in the case i need the input later on and can't remember at one go. thx

Comment: In the filter you can also use the `$key` argument as a condition, to target specific rates…

Comment: hi, i try to solve the following issue since two days - any help would be  greatly appreciated  https://stackoverflow.com/q/48271160/9036446