# Sort WooCommerce Products from a product category and custom meta_key

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I'm successfully filtering ALL my WordPress posts by Likes (count) with a Custom Plugin (and meta_key) which also let me filter the most liked posts in categories. I display (query) the result in a custom page template. Everything works fine.

The Like function works also on WooCommerce Products. But so far I was not able to set up a page where I sort the Products (post_type) the same way in a specific shop category as I do it with my posts. The closest i came was to display the most liked posts on the page BUT the sorting for a category does not filter the posts - it displays the same as in the main page. The category List and the url call for the category links are working fine.

**NOTE:** THE URL query-string "product-cato" is a custom one - I'm using a ajax filter plugin which uses this query-string and the category id like `.../?product-cato=6`Please do not mix it up which `product_cat` for example

This is what I came up so far - beginning with the code for the posts (which works fine). Any idea how to solve this issue?

**The query** (works fine)

```
if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
    $args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_recoed',
    'meta_compare' => '>',
    'meta_value' => '0',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'category_name' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['category']),
    'paged' => $paged
    );
} 

 query_posts($args);
```

**The Category List to Filter the Post in each Category** (works fine)

```
<?php $categories = get_categories();

foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li>
        <a class="popular-categories" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>?category=<?php echo $category->category_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a> 
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Now the WooCommerce Query and Category Part where I am stuck

**The Query for the Products post_type**

```
    if (isset($_GET['product-cato'])) {
    $args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_recoed',
    'meta_compare' => '>',
    'meta_value' => '0',
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'taxonomy' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_cat']),
    'paged' => $paged
);
        
query_posts($args);
```

**The Category List to Filter the Post in each Shop-Category**

```
<?php
    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
    $count = count($product_categories);

    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) { ?>
        <li>
            <a class="popular-categories" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>?product-cato=<?php echo $product_category->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $product_category->name; ?></a>
        </li>
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As **Product Categories** are a **custom taxonomy** `'product_cat'`, use a **`tax_query`** instead.

So instead of wrong:

```
'taxonomy' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_cat'])
```

… use this *(defining correctly the **`'field'`** argument)*:

```
'tax_query' => array( // the product category query
    array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'term_id', // (also 'name' or 'slug')  <==   <==   <==   <==   <== 
        'terms'    => sanitize_text_field($_GET['product-cato']),
    ),
),
```

> Check also in `sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_cat'])` that **`'product_cat'` is the right slug**, as you use also `product-cato`…
>
> If `sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_cat'])` is not a product category **"slug"**, you should need to change `'field'    => 'term_id',` with the correct field type (`'name'` or `'slug'`).

So your code should be *(defining correctly the **`'field'`** argument)*:

```
if (isset($_GET['product-cato'])) {
    query_posts( array(
        'meta_key' => '_recoed',
        'meta_compare' => '>',
        'meta_value' => '0',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        //'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        // The product category query
        'tax_query' => array( 
            array( 
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'term_id', // (also 'name' or 'slug') <==   <==   <==   <==
                'terms'    => sanitize_text_field($_GET['product-cato']),
            ),
        ),
    ) );
}
```

It should work …

Comment: You are awesome @LoicTheAztec - `'field'    => 'term_id', and ` `'terms'    => sanitize_text_field($_GET['product-cato']),` worked! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: OFF TOPIC: me again :) Any idea how to solve the following problem [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328797/reinitialise-woocommerce-scripts-again-after-loading-products-with-wordpress-inf

Comment: @evavienna I am not skilled in related theming as infinite scroll feature... Sorry.

Comment: its not about the infinite scroll - its about initializing a script - i only need to know how to call the add-to-cart-variation.min.js again... thx