# Get current Category Name on a page which filters posts by Category and custom meta_key

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I'm successfully filtering all my WordPress posts (in a custom page template) by Likes (count) with a Custom Plugin (and meta_key) which also let me filter the most liked posts in a specific category with the following

```
if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
    $args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_recoed',
    'meta_compare' => '>',
    'meta_value' => '0',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'category_name' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['category']),
    'paged' => $paged
    );
} 

query_posts($args);

get_template_part('index');
```

**The Category List to Filter the Posts for each Category** (works fine)

```
<?php $categories = get_categories('exclude=' . implode(',', my_blog_cats()) . ', 1'); ?>

<?php if ($categories) { ?>

<?php $categories = get_categories(); ?>

<?php foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li>
        <a class="popular-categories" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>?category=<?php echo $category->category_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a> 
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

The url after filtering the posts for example - looks like

```
.../hot-posts/?category=new-posts-category
```

**Any idea how to echo only the current category name on the current page?** In the case of the example it would be "New Post Category"

Comment: So far im aware of it - yes

Comment: You need to display the category name of the `$_GET['category']` term ID on this page?

Comment: With `<?php echo sanitize_title($_GET['category']); ?>` im getting the right category names - but with dashes like "new-post-category". Hope this helps

Comment: yes - but i have no clue how to get the name

Comment: Ok So as you are not sure (and me too either) you have all possibilities in my answer…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 3 possibilities *(the taxonomy for WP categories is `category`)*:

1) **An ID** - If `$_GET['category']` is a WP `category` **term ID** you will use:

```
if( isset($_GET['category'] ) && term_exists( intval($_GET['category']), 'category' ) ){
    $term = get_term( intval($_GET['category']), 'category' );
    echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>';
}
```

2) **A SLUG** - If `$_GET['category']` is a WP `category` **term SLUG** you will use:

```
if( isset($_GET['category'] ) && term_exists( sanitize_text_field($_GET['category']), 'category' ) ){
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', sanitize_text_field($_GET['category']), 'category' );
    echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>';
}
```

3) **A NAME** - If it is already a WP `category` **terme NAME** just use:

```
if( isset($_GET['category'] ) && term_exists( sanitize_text_field($_GET['category']), 'category' ) )
    echo '<p>' . sanitize_text_field($_GET['category']) . '</p>';
```

> But dont use `sanitize_title()` on WP `category` **terme NAME** as it will become a **term SLUG**

Comment: The second one works fine. Another quick question reagarding one of your previous answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280321/9036446. The products query displays sometimes some products after going to the next page twice and sometimes it displays different products after reloading (f5 or click on the categoy) - i never saw something weird like this. it always happens after 3 to 5 page reloads - any idea? Thank you so much.

Comment: @evavienna I don't know for the moment, because I have just make your initial code working for what you asked… This is complicate as you are making a lot of different customizations, and something else can interact with it…