# Get WooCommerce product Category Name by it's ID from a GET request

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, custom-taxonomy

I'm filtering my WooCommerce Products on a custom page template by category and a custom meta_key. Now I'm trying to echo the category name in which the products are filtered.

The url after filtering the products looks like

```
.../online-shop/popular-products/?product-cato=23
```

23 is the ID of the Category. I was able to get (or echo) the id by using the following

```
<?php echo sanitize_text_field($_GET['product-cato']);?>
```

**Any idea how to get the category name with the available category ID (in this case 23)?**

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_name ?

Comment: @AlexVand This is not for custom taxonomy like product category, so it will not work for WooCommerce product categories…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec you are right - don't work.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Comment: @CBroe You don't need to use `get_term_by()` as it's already a **term ID**, so it works with a simple `get_term()`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the following:

```
// Testing that $_GET['product-cato'] has been requested and that the product category exists.
if( isset( $_GET['product-cato'] ) && term_exists( intval($_GET['product-cato']), 'product_cat' ) ){
    // Get the corresponding WP_Term object
    $term = get_term( intval($_GET['product-cato']), 'product_cat' );
    //Display the term name for the product category
    echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>';
}
```

Tested and works.

> You will **not need to sanitize** the Product category name, as it's already filtered by the conditions and by `intval()` function. So it's secure.

Comment: This works perfect! Thx - slowly but surely you are getting my personal Hero :) I need almost the same for posts - i asked this today https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525133/9036446 Maybe you can help me out! best

Comment: @evavienna Thanks… I only answer WooCommerce tagged questions mostly. But I will make an exception, so I will look to it and try to answer if I can.

Comment: :) Sounds awesome!